# Multiple explicit constructors and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, constructor, implicit-conversion, function-call, explicit

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private:
        std::string m_data;

    public:
        Foo() = default;

        explicit Foo(double value);
        explicit Foo(float value);
        explicit Foo(int64_t value);
        explicit Foo(bool value);
        explicit Foo(const std::string& value);
        explicit Foo(const char* value);
};
```

... because I'd like to be able to construct `Foo` instances from integers, booleans, floats, doubles, and so on.

Let's say I have another class `Bar`, which has a method that takes a reference to `const Foo`:

```
void append(const Foo& foo);
```

Why does the compiler complain when I do the following?

```
instanceOfBar.append(3.5);
```

> Reference to type Foo could not bind to an rvalue of type 'float'

```
instanceOfBar.append(4);
```

> Reference to type Foo could not bind to an rvalue of type 'int'

```
instanceOfBar.append(true);
```

> Reference to type Foo could not bind to an rvalue of type 'bool'

I am using GCC 12.2.1

Comment: *Why the compiler complains when i do this `instanceOfBar.append(3.5);
`?* The compiler complains because `3.5` is not a `Foo`.  Since the Foo constructor is `explicit`, you'd need to do `instanceOfBar.append(Foo{3.5});`.

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, your understanding of what an `explicit` constructor is, how it's different from non-explicit constructors, and what, exactly, is unclear to you about this compilation error, given the presence of explicit constructors?

Comment: @Eljay 3.5 is not a Foo, but the compiler should automatically and implicitly convert it to a Foo, calling the relative Foo constructor (if there's one, and i wrote it, so it should). I was wondering why it does not do it, or, which is the correct way to accomplish this

Comment: What does "relative Foo constructor" mean? Where is it?

Comment: @HeapOverflow "*the compiler should automatically and **implicitly** convert it to a Foo ... I was wondering why it does not do it*" - you just stated the answer for yourself. You **disabled implicit conversions** when you declared the constructors as `explicit`. That means you have to call the constructors **explicitly** instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think he meant *relevant* not *relative*

Comment: *... but the compiler should automatically and implicitly convert it to a Foo...* You told the compiler **not** to automatically and implicitly convert it to a Foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructors of the class `Foo` are declared with the function specifier `explicit`. So, you need to convert argument expressions explicitly to the type `Foo` to allow the function `append()` to bind them to the const lvalue reference.

As, for example:

```
instanceOfBar.append( Foo( 4 ) );
```

In fact, you are trying to do something like the following:

```
struct A { explicit A( int ) {} };
const A &a = 10;
```

This code will not compile because the compiler can not *implicitly* convert the integer constant `10` to the type `A`.

But, if you remove the function specifier `explicit` in the constructor declaration, then this code snippet will compile:

```
struct A { A( int ) {} };
const A &a = 10;
```

Comment: Ok this is the right answer, but i have another related question. How can i still have for example instanceOfBar.append(true) and be able to construct a Foo object from a bool if i remove the explicit keyword? The compiler says "call to append(true) is ambiguos" in this case, because it doesn't know if i am using append(bool) or append(int) or something else, so i initially fixed using the explicit keyword that led me to this situation. Maybe the question should have been formulated on this topic instead

Comment: @HeapOverflow If you have a constructor with the parameter of the type bool then its should be called. You can ask a new question with a minimal reproducible program.